# how can i call modal on bootstrap via javascript/jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I was having a problem on calling bootstrap modal on a simple button or link maybe because its having a conflict with my select2 plugin (which I'm not really sure of) ,by the way I did just append the button to the select2 drop down, here is my javascript that wont work:

```
 $(".select2-drop").append('<table><tr><td><button class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalAdd">New Supplier</button></td></tr></table>');`
```

because of this I'm just trying to do a javascript/jquery function to open the modal ( dont know if its the best way.)

here is my javascript code:

```
$(".select2-drop").append('<table><tr><td><button class="btn" onClick="modal() ">New Supplier</button></td></tr></table>');
```

tried to alert some message on it and it worked:

```
function modal(){
   alert("pressed");
}
```

My question is, How can I call modal on bootstrap via javascript/jquery function?

any kind of help/suggestions would really be appreciated, Thank you and have a good Day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$('#modalID').modal('show')
```

By HTML

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#yourmodalid">
    Launch modal
</button>
```

Comment: the second one wont work on me, as I said above it maybe have any conflict with my select2 :)

Comment: yeah, the second one works if I put the button outside the dropdown box, but when I try to append it on my select2's dropdown using jquerys append, I dont know but Its not working anymore!

Answer (score 1):

If you want it completely "mechanical" see this example :

fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/RvJV8/**

```js
$("#btnOpen").click(function() {
    $("#myModal").modal();
});
```

---

Did you ever tried this? It works ..

```js
$(".select2-drop").append('<table><tr><td><button class="btn" onclick="$(&quot;#myModal&quot;).modal();">New Supplier</button></td></tr></table>');
```

forked fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/3uZAZ/**

Comment: thank you for your answer @davidkonrad, I really appreciate it, but I just dont know why its not working, and the only thing thats working on me is when I add the onClick property on the element and specifying it to a function. Im really confused why its happening, but anyways as long as its working I will be fine with it :)

Comment: @melvnberd, know this is closed but see update (just for demonstrating). You dont have to call an extra function, just place the code in your onclick-handler. BTW, the correct syntax is `onclick`, not `onClick` (it will fail in a HTML-validator)